# Google Documents List Api - Paging results without feed.getNextLink()

Tags: java, hyperlink, google-data-api, google-docs-api

I have been looking for ways to gain access to different pages more quickly in the Google Documents List Api, and to do this I'd like to be able to start my downloads at a specific part of the list, ie if a user has 400 documents, be able to start downloading at document 300. However I have now realised that the start-index parameter no longer works ( see here http://code.google.com/apis/documents/changelog.html#release-Version-3.0 )

Has anyone found a way to access different parts of a user's documents list without using the feed.getNextLink() method? I would use this but you have to download the first part of their documents each time making it pointless.

I have had a look at the url returned by getNextLink and it includes "?start-key=EAIaUAsSADpKEGQhvg7_ZoxPRJQo76P_9gVCNX__AP8AOPDQpn_HysvGyszNyszNy8fRzsvRjMesq9LKqry2ms2ttJacoMyxvM_Sy4j_AP_-SAIMIgsJgFkvD8cAAAAgBg" 
which I investigated, but it turns out this cannot be generated yourself, and is generated server-side ( see here: http://code.google.com/apis/apps/profiles/developers_guide_protocol.html#retrieving_with_query )

So, anyone have a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to do index-based queries on the Documents List API.  Results must be paged through linearly using next links.

However, once you've fetched a set of resources from the API, you can use the new [Changes feed](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Changes) to keep that set up to date, without the need to requery the entire set.